How to Skip a Stage in a Pipeline Based on Condition Without Failing the current and next stage
I'm working on a pipeline and I want to implement a check that verifies if a certain condition is met. If the condition is not met, I want to skip the next stage instead of failing it.
My current pipeline looks like this:
stages:
- stage: Terraform_Plan
  displayName: Plan
  jobs:
  - job: Terraform_Plan
    displayName: Plan 

    steps:
    
    - powershell: |
        # made it shorter to get a point
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges;isOutput=true]false"

      displayName: Detect any Terraform changes
      name: test

# new stage here as placeholder
- stage: Any_Changes
  displayName: Changes
  variables:
     varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan.Terraform_Plan.outputs['test.anyTfChanges'] ]
  condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), eq('true', 'true'), eq(variables['varFromA'], 'true')))

- stage: Terraform_Apply
  displayName: Apply
  dependsOn: Terraform_Plan
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: dev
    displayName: Apply Terraform
    condition: # run only when Any_Changes stage suceeded, if not skip this step. 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo "1"

I want to insert a stage between Plan and Apply that checks if the conditions from the previous stage are met. if yes, run Apply. If not, skip Apply without failing any of steps.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!


I want to insert a stage between Plan and Apply that checks if the conditions from the previous stage are met. if yes, run Apply. If not, skip Apply without failing any of steps.

The varFromA is defined at stage level, in the stage condition, it cannot be expanded. Please fix the condition as below for stage Any_Changes:
condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), eq('true', 'true'), eq(dependencies.Terraform_Plan.outputs['Terraform_Plan.test.anyTfChanges'], 'true')))

the variable varFromA only can be used in job level condition:
- stage: Any_Changes
  displayName: Changes
  dependsOn: Terraform_Plan
  variables:
     varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan.Terraform_Plan.outputs['test.anyTfChanges'] ]
 
  jobs:
    - job: job1
      condition: eq(variables['varFromA'], 'true')
      steps:
        - script: echo job1 in stage Any_Changes $(varFromA)

And for the  Terraform_Apply stage, change the dependsOn to Any_Changes. You can remove condition on this stage, as it will run only when dependsOn stage succeeds by default.
The whole yaml as below:
stages:
- stage: Terraform_Plan
  displayName: Plan
  jobs:
  - job: Terraform_Plan
    displayName: Plan 

    steps:
    
    - powershell: |
        # made it shorter to get a point
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges;isOutput=true]false"
      displayName: Detect any Terraform changes
      name: test

# new stage here as placeholder
- stage: Any_Changes
  displayName: Changes
  dependsOn: Terraform_Plan
  variables:
     varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan.Terraform_Plan.outputs['test.anyTfChanges'] ]
  condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'), eq('true', 'true'), eq(dependencies.Terraform_Plan.outputs['Terraform_Plan.test.anyTfChanges'], 'true')))
  #condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'), eq('true', 'true'), eq(variables['varFromA'], 'true')))
  jobs:
    - job: job1
      steps:
        - script: echo job1 in stage Any_Changes $(varFromA)

- stage: Terraform_Apply
  displayName: Apply
  dependsOn: Any_Changes
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: dev
    displayName: Apply Terraform
    #condition: # run only when Any_Changes stage suceeded, if not skip this step. 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo "1"


If anyTfChanges value is set as true at first stage, which means will condition meets, it will run all stages.


I checked for main branch in condition of stage Any_Changes in sample yaml, you can change to master if needed, thanks.
